# Shiny app: Seeking more detailed profile

Tags: r, shiny, profiling

My app takes 54440 ms to initialize/open, which is significantly more than what I want. I profiled it first in small chunks (nothing useful found there) then profiled the whole thing. The flame graph below documents running the app (me clicking the play button) until the app is fully open (by open, I mean fully functioning with nothing still loading).

As you can see in the flame graph below, the first ~15000 ms are well documented, but after that, "runApp" is the only thing there until the app opens.

How do I learn more about what is running during that time? I want to make my app initialize faster.

I cannot share my code because it's a private project, but I would love to know if there are any more detailed profiling methods y'all know of. Thanks!

[image: Flame Graph of whole app profile from app start to when app is open]

Answer (score 0):

I found that my script was occupying 100% of my core, which was the bottleneck. You can't multi-thread R, so I switched to MRAN which allows me to multi-thread.